# Ordering items by grouped quantity

Tags: c#, linq

I want to order some posts by how many times a user has posted a post.

I have the following:

```
IList<User> orderTopContributors = 
    this.GetPosts()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Author.Id)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AuthorCount = x.Count()
    })
    .OrderByDescending( x => x.AuthorCount )
    .ToList();
```

Where am i going wrong? There is an error with the casting:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0266  Cannot
>   implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< Items>>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: ``OrderByDescending``

Comment: Thanks for noticing that hehe.

Comment: When you apply `Select` clause you get an `IEnumerable` object whose elements are of the new type defined in the `Select`, so, when you put 'new' inside the `Select` clause, it does that Linq returns a `IEnumerable` list of new type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***tl;dr: Use the [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) method***

You have few mistakes:

- First of all ***(you fixed this one in an edit)***, you should use `OrderByDescending` in order to get the order from the biggest to the smallest.
- *Next* ***(you fixed this one in an edit)****, you are expecting to receive `IList<User>`, either change it to `IEnumrable<User>` or add `.ToList()` in the end of your Linq.*
- **Lastly, if you want to flatten your groups to a single list use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) and select your flattened lists**:

Example code:

```
IList<User> orderTopContributors = GetPosts()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AuthorCount = x.Count(),
        Posts = x
    })
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.AuthorCount)
   .SelectMany(x => x.Posts)
   .ToList();
```

When you are using `.GroupBy` you turn your `IEnumerable<User>` to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<User>>` since there are **few groups (many times many)**, by using the [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) method you state which `IEnumerable<T>` you want to take from each group and aggregate it to the final result:

***Example pseudo:***

```
var Users = new List<User>
{
    { UserID = 576, PostId = 7 },
    { UserID = 576, PostId = 4 },
    { UserID = 4, PostId = 2 },
    { UserID = 2, PostId = 5 },
    { UserID = 2, PostId = 1 },
    { UserID = 576, PostId = 9 }
}

var Ordered = Users
    .GroupBy(x => x.UserID)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        AuthorCount = x.Count(),
        Posts = x
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.AuthorCount)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Posts)
    .ToList();
```

`Ordered` is now:

```
List<User>
{
    { UserID = 576, PostId = 7 },
    { UserID = 576, PostId = 4 },
    { UserID = 576, PostId = 9 },
    { UserID = 2, PostId = 5 },
    { UserID = 2, PostId = 1 },
    { UserID = 4, PostId = 2 }
}
```

Comment: I modified my question a bit, ir ealise how it was confusing

Comment: Read what i wrote about `.SelectMany()`

Comment: Thanks, I'll alter your code to the solution, I was being a noob aswell